# Firestore Error: The query requires an index

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing some problem when use angular 2 to query data from Firestore.

Could anyone please help me by checking it and tell me where I have done wrong ?

My error:

> ERROR Error: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/admin-e8a7b/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EgR0ZW1wGgcKA3VpZBACGg0KCXN0YXJ0ZWRBdBADGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAM
> at new FirestoreError (vendor.bundle.js:19925)

This is my code:

```
getTemp(uid): Observable<any> {
let temps = [];
var today = new Date();
return this.afs.collection<Temps>('temp', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid).orderBy('startedAt', 'desc')).snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(action => {
      const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Temps;
      console.log(data.temp);
      return data.temp;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I need your help !

Answer (score 22):

This error is happening because by default Firestore does not require additional indexes for queries that **only use equality clauses**, therefore  that is not your case.

To make your query work you only need to click  on the link of the error message and create a new index for your query in the Firebase Console.

To get to know more about how Firestore indexes work you can read on the [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing?hl=lt)

Answer (score 4):

Click on the link provided. If it doesn't take you to the correct page, if you get this error:

```
The project xxx either does not exist, or user doesn't have permission
```

sign out the current user, and login as your Firebase user.

You will get the index suggested for your query.

> Composite indexes are required for queries that include specific
>   values and a range or order.

When you run these queries, they would have bad performance and wouldn't scale well.

Every time you change your query with different fields, combining range, equal to or order by operators, you will have to create a new index. If you only use whereEqualTo operators you don't need to.

It might take a while to create the index depending on your data size.

Answer (score 0):

This error may also be happening because one of the fields you queried does not exist in a document scanned

Answer (score 0):

From doc:

> Managing indexes
>
> Cloud Firestore ensures query performance by requiring an index for
>   every query. The indexes required for the most basic queries are
>   automatically created for you. As you use and test your app, Cloud
>   Firestore generates error messages that help you create additional
>   indexes your app requires. This page describes how to manage your
>   single-field and composite indexes.
>
> Create a missing index through an error message
>
> If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map
>   to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes
>   a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.

[Read more there](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing?hl=lt).

IF you are in VS code or any IDE, just press ctrl + left click it will bring you to create missing index. If that did not bring you to the create index dialog. Copy paste the url to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase hosting you can add the following to your `firestore.indexes.json` file:

```
{
  "collectionGroup": "temp",
  "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldPath": "uid",
      "order": "ASCENDING"
    },
    {
      "fieldPath": "startedAt",
      "order": "DESCENDING"
    }
  ]
}
```

When you deploy Firebase it will automatically build these indexes.

You can alternatively deploy the indexes by themselves with this command:

`firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes`

Comment: Here, how to add Exemptions for a Single-field indexing?