# filter and orderBy on the diffrent field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm want to filler user and order by time.But it's not working.

```
await firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('chats')
                .where('users', 'array-contains', _usr.email)
                .orderBy('lastmessage')
                .onSnapshot(async res => {
                    const chats = res.docs.map(_doc => _doc.data());
                    await this.setState({
                        email: _usr.email,
                        chats: chats,
                        friends: []
                    });
                })
```

error is

```
Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here
```

Comment: were you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore automatically generates indexes on each individual field, which allows you to perform many queries without any extra setup work. But your query here requires an additional index that is not automatically generated, so you will have to set it up in the Firebase console yourself.

If you look at the error message in the JavaScript console of your browser, you will see that it contains a link. If you click that link, it takes you to a page in the Firebase console where all information is prepopulated to generate the correct index for you.

So:

1. Click the link in the error message.
2. Click the <kbd>Create index</kbd> button in the page you get to.
3. Wait a few moments until the index is completely generated.

Also see:

- [Firestore index error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142392/firestore-index-error)