# how to use orderBy after .where(arrayContain) flutter firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Am trying to get my chat list using flutter in firebase firestore and this is my code

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getUserChats(String uid) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatRoom")
        .where('users', arrayContains: uid)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

[image: firebase image]

So now i want to be able to order by lastChatTime so it can be in a descending order but i don't know how cause when i use `orderBy("lastChatTime", descending: true)` it throws an error

```
W/Firestore( 2300): (22.1.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(chatRoom where users array_contains # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@e87d45c
W/Firestore( 2300): integer_value: 0
W/Firestore( 2300): string_value: "JFof2JR4UpS0H03xo7aVYdcfvJi1" order by -lastChatTime, -__name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/ohms-5fd20/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Cktwcm9qZWN0cy9vaG1zLTVmZDIwL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9jaGF0Um9vbS9pbmRleGVzL18QARoJCgV1c2VycxgBGhAKDGxhc3RDaGF0VGltZRACGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAI, cause=null}
```

Please how can i go about doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you're trying to run requires an index that is not yet defined on your database. In the error message is a URL:

> The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/ohms-5fd20/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Cktwcm9qZWN0cy9vaG1zLTVmZDIwL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9jaGF0Um9vbS9pbmRleGVzL18QARoJCgV1c2VycxgBGhAKDGxhc3RDaGF0VGltZRACGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAI.

If **you** click that URL, it takes you to a screen in the Firebase console where you can create the necessary index with a single click - all fields are pre-populated.

Also see:

- [Firestore index error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142392/firestore-index-error)

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, look at you error log, it says that you need to create an index for this query you are trying to run. It also says: click on this link...etc.

Click on that link and it'll take you to firebase and everything will be setup, just press "enable index".

Happy coding!